# Problem showing Linq IEnumerable Except to DataGridView

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, ienumerable, hashset

I have two hashsets that I want to except to get the distinct data:

```
var dataA = new HashSet<string>();
var dataB = new HashSet<string>();
var exceptA = dataA.Except(dataB);
var exceptB = dataB.Except(dataA);
var result = exceptA.Union(exceptB);
var container = new HashSet<string>(result);
dgv_B.DataSource = container.ToList();
```

My problem is when I insert the container into the datageid, this is my result:

[image: result]

And this is the raw data from breakpoints:

[image]

How can I display the text in the DGV?

Comment: Try this `var container = new HashSet<string>(dataA.Concat(dataB));`

Comment: What's `dgv_B`?

Comment: I can reproduce the same behavior in LinqPad.

Comment: Returns blank DGV

Comment: It seems that the DGV does not work with lists of primitive types. It expects objects and analyzes their properties to generate the columns (a `string` has a `Length` property). Try something like this instead: `dgv_B.DataSource = container.Select(s => new { Value = s }).ToList();`

Comment: dgv_B are usernames, simple strings.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride nice, that solved my problem, can you explain me your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by fellow @GoodNightNerdPride:

It seems that the DGV does not work with lists of primitive types. It expects objects and analyzes their properties to generate the columns (a string has a Length property). Try something like this instead:

```
dgv_B.DataSource = container.Select(s => new { Value = s }).ToList();
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better :D